# What " the Garcias' pool refer to?

Tags: word-meaning

John and Brittany, along with several of their school friends, were invited for a swim at the Garcias' pool.

As far as I know, we use "s' " to say that something belongs to a family.  Is the Garcia a family? I know you might say context is essential, but I just want to know if it could relates to a group of relatives or a group in an office or something like that and not necessarily a group of people in a family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be anything. An apostrophe *''s'"* suggests possession. Now *Garcias* could be the family (Just like 'the Obamas' family doctor avoided the press conference') or it could be the name of some swimming pool (Just like Markos' Pool).

As you just said, **context** will help us answering this! :)

Comment: @StoneyB Frankly, I'm terrible at identifying surnames and names of foreigners. Cannot help it, sir!